# собрать все зависимости в один DLL в C# проект

Tags: c#, dll, зависимости

У меня есть проект dll (dllMy) котрая использует ряд других сторонних dll(dllDep) которые я включаю к Reference в проект.  Мне необходимо в номо проекте обращатся не только к dllMy но и dllDep. Есть ли способ собрать все зависимости в одну dll (dllMy) и использовать из нового проекта приложения.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630

Comment: @iluxa1810 а конкретней можно ? нашел только примеры как собирают из n dll  .exe а как из n dll собрать 1 dll ??

Comment: [это?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12516928/312041)